# Generating public/private keys in GnuPG from C/C++ and arguments

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, gnupg, openpgp

The newer version of  GnuPG which is  2.1 has the function "gpgme_op_createkey" in the library **GPGme**. The older one this:

```
gpgme_op_genkey(mContext, def.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
```

Which accepts data in this format:

```
char *def = "<GnupgKeyParms format=\"internal\"> \n"
                " Key-Type: default \n"
                " Subkey-Type: default \n"
                " Name-Real: Joe Tester3 \n"
                " Name-Comment: with stupid passphrase \n"
                " Name-Email: joe3@foo.bar \n"
                " Expire-Date: 0 \n"
                " Passphrase: abc \n"
                " </GnupgKeyParms>";
```

However, the newer version of GnuPG accepts fewer arguments:

```
  gpgme_op_createkey(gpgme_ctx_t ctx, const char *userid, const char *algo, unsigned long reserved, unsigned long expires,
                        gpgme_key_t certkey, unsigned int flags);
```

How can I provide to the newer function "gpgme_op_createkey", say, passphrase? subkey-type?

Also, if it's ECC, how can I choose which curve to use? For example "ed25519"?

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the passphrase through the callback mechanism. You have to set pinentry-mode to loopback and then set a passphrase callback.

As for subkey-type, this is not exposed. GnuPG will decide based on the capabilities. If you want to control it generate a key with only the "Certify" capability and then use "gpgme_op_createsubkey" to add explict subkeys.

The curve can be set through the algo name. If you want ECC you can just use "future-default" as the algo name. This will create a cv25519 / ed25519 key.

gpgme_op_createkey ends up using "gpg --quick-gen-key" so you might want to read the manpage of that command.

Note that for c++ you could also use the c++ language bindings of GPGME which help with memory management and are a bit nicer to use for c++ hackers.